# How to use FormattedMessage inside an option tag in React 0.14?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to migrate my application from React 0.12 to React 0.14 and am having trouble with option elements that use [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) FormattedMessage objects placed inside select tags.

Here is a sample JSX code:

```
<select>
<option value="value1"><FormattedMessage message={this.getIntlMessage('key1')}/></option>
<option value="value2"><FormattedMessage message={this.getIntlMessage('key2')}/></option>
</select>
```

This code works fine in React 0.12 and I see my translated option elements.

In react 0.14, I got this error:

```
Only strings and numbers are supported as <option> children.
```

I traced the message to this changeset in React that happened earlier this year:

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3847/files

How can I fix this issue? I can't be the only one trying to use internationalized option elements?

Answer (score 15):

This has always been an issue. React < 0.14 used to silently accept invalid DOM structure, in your case `<span>` elements inside `<option>` elements. The browser would then correct the DOM structure, and cause the virtual DOM managed by React to be out of sync with the real thing. You wouldn't see errors until you tried to re-render existing components instead of just re-mounting them.

`react-intl` V2.0.0, which will ship with support for React 0.14, allows you to use the Function-As-Child pattern to customize the way your `Formatted*` components render. See the "Function-As-Child Support" paragraph on [this issue](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/162).

In your case, you would do:

```js
<FormattedMessage message={this.getIntlMessage('key1')}>
  {(message) => <option value="value1">{message}</option>}
</FormattedMessage>
<FormattedMessage message={this.getIntlMessage('key2')}>
  {(message) => <option value="value2">{message}</option>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

I don't think there's a way to achieve this on the current stable version, 1.2.1.

Comment: If the OP doesn't need to do formatting could they just do `this.getIntlMessage('key1')` inside the option? Bit of an oversight not to expose the full underlying translation method imo

Comment: You're right, in the OP's case, `this.getIntlMessage('key1')` would return the correct message. Note that the V2.0.0 API does expose translation methods on context.

Comment: That seems like it will work as long as I don't use any placeholders.... I can't believe there is no stable way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and solved it via the injectIntl().

> This function is used to wrap a component and will inject the intl context object created by the IntlProvider as a prop on the wrapped component. Using the HOC factory function alleviates the need for context to be a part of the public API.

That means all you have to do is wrap your component with the injectIntl function, like that:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {defineMessages, injectIntl, intlShape} from 'react-intl';

const messages = defineMessages({
    firstoption: {
        id: 'mycomponent.firstoption',
        defaultMessage: 'Coffee',
    },
    secondoption: {
        id: 'mycomponent.secondoption',
        defaultMessage: 'Tea',
    }
});

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;

        return (
          <div>
             <select>
                <option value="value1">{formatMessage(messages.firstoption)}</option>
                <option value="value2">{formatMessage(messages.secondoption)}</option>
             </select>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

MyComponent = {
    intl   : intlShape.isRequired
};

export default injectIntl(MyComponent)
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: how about if I have to use the formatting on multiple components. Where can I locally inject the intl prop so that when user calls for formatting messages, he does not have to inject the intl every time

Comment: So when you use the component, what do you pass in to the required intl attribute? I assumed this was handled by the injection, but I get an error in my editor where the component is used saying that a required attribute intl is missing. Is that just an editor issue?

Comment: "MyComponent =" should probably be "MyComponent.propTypes ="...?

Answer (score 2):

As a little bit better alternative to @Alexandre Kirszenberg answer, it's also possible to inject `intl` object into component and use `formatMessage` function directly,

```
import { injectIntl, intlShape, defineMessages, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

const AddressForm = ({ intl, street, number, postalCode, city, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <form id="paymentAddress">
      // ...
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="country"><FormattedMessage { ...messages.country } />:</label>
        <div>
          <select name="country">
            <option value="DE">{intl.formatMessage(messages.de)}</option>
            <option value="UK">{intl.formatMessage(messages.uk)}</option>
            <option value="CH">{intl.formatMessage(messages.ch)}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
};

AddressForm.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `react-intl` v4.0.0 you can do this:

```
    <select
      className="content"
      name="type-enquiry"
      defaultValue="Type of Enquiry"
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
     >
      <option name="options" disabled hidden>
                Choose
      </option>
        <FormattedMessage id='contact.enquiry.a' key={'op' + '-' + 'a'}>
           {(message) => <option value='a'>{message}</option>}
        </FormattedMessage>
        <FormattedMessage id='contact.enquiry.b' key={'op' + '-' + 'b'}>
           {(message) => <option value='b'>{message}</option>}
        </FormattedMessage>
        <FormattedMessage id='contact.enquiry.c' key={'op' + '-' + 'c'}>
           {(message) => <option value='c'>{message}</option>}
        </FormattedMessage>
    </select>
```

[example code](https://github.com/kalwalt/gatsby-starter-i18n-bulma/pull/128/commits/587a09bdb6adec41610b089bb027ad75b608d13d)

Answer (score 0):

Use `injectIntl` to wrap the component you want to use the API inside ,so you can use the API, such as `formattedMessage` and so on. See [react-intl/wiki/API](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API)

Answer (score 0):

```
"react-intl": "2.4.0",
```

```
"babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.4.0",
```

**working snippet**

```
<FormattedMessage
   key={key}
   id={popoverOptions[key].id}
   defaultMessage={popoverOptions[key].defaultMessage}>
   {(message) => <option value={key}>{message}</option>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

**Whole Scenario**

```
"reactstrap": "5.0.0-beta",
```

```
import { Input} from "reactstrap";
import {FormattedMessage} from "react-intl";
```

```
<Input 
        value={filter.status} 
        onChange={this.onFilterChange} 
        type="select"
        name="select" id="exampleSelect">
        {Object.keys(popoverOptions).map((key, index) => {
            return (
                    <FormattedMessage
                     key={key}
                     id={popoverOptions[key].id}
                     defaultMessage={popoverOptions[key].defaultMessage}>
                          {(message) => <option value={key}>{message}</option>}
                    </FormattedMessage>
                 )
         })}
</Input>
```