# React-Intl How to use FormattedMessage in input placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, react-starter-kit

I'm unsure how to get the values from

```
<FormattedMessage {...messages.placeholderIntlText} />
```

into a placeholder format like input:

```
<input placeholder={<FormattedMessage {...messages.placeholderIntlText} />} />
```

as it would return [Object object] in the actual placeholder. Is there a way to get the actual correct value?

Comment: The intl and injection worked for me from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441524/how-to-use-formattedmessage-inside-an-option-tag-in-react-0-14

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The `<Formatted... />` React components in `react-intl` are meant to be used in rendering scenarios and are not meant to be used in placeholders, alternate text, etc. They render HTML, not plain text, which is not useful in your scenario.

Instead, `react-intl` provides a [lower level API](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API) for exactly this same reason. The rendering components themselves use this API under the hoods to format the values into HTML. Your scenario probably requires you to use the lower level `formatMessage(...)` API.

You should inject the `intl` object into your component by using the `injectIntl` HOC and then just format the message through the API.

Example:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

const ChildComponent = ({ intl }) => {
  const placeholder = intl.formatMessage({id: 'messageId'});
  return(
     <input placeholder={placeholder} />
  );
}

ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired
}

export default injectIntl(ChildComponent);
```

Please note that I'm using some ES6 features here, so adapt according to your setup.

Comment: Yeah this response is good, but, I still think the purpose of this HoC is very confusing.
`const ChildComponent = (props, context) => {` and `context.intl.formatMessage()` do exactly the same thing and you don't need this HoC.
I don't understand why all the responses here are not even suggesting this.

Comment: @NicolasRenon, this answer is two and half years old. By now I would assume other/better options are available. Still, this particular example is of no particular interest but in a bigger scope `ChildComponent` could have any other kind of logic you'd like (formatting of many messages, for instance). It's not meant to be a one size fits all solution. It's just an example.

Answer (score 41):

- You can use `intl` prop from `injectIntl` HoC
- You can also provide function as child component:

```
<FormattedMessage {...messages.placeholderIntlText}>
  {(msg) => (<input placeholder={msg} />)}
</FormattedMessage>
```

Comment: this one is easier to apply

Comment: @Shalkam No, it is not. This one blots the source code with unnecessary <FormattedMessage/> tags.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan I write down both possibilities. Depends on case. If you are rendering DOM element and you don't want wrap it in <span>, you should use second example.

Answer (score 21):

It's july 2019 and react-intl 3 beta is shipped with a [useIntl](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/API.md#useintl-hook-currently-available-in-300-beta) hook to make these kind of translations easier:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useIntl, FormattedDate} from 'react-intl';

const FunctionComponent: React.FC<{date: number | Date}> = ({date}) => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  return (
    <span title={intl.formatDate(date)}>
      <FormattedDate value={date} />
    </span>
  );
};

export default FunctionComponent;
```

And then you can make custom hooks to use the methods provided by the API:

```
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl'

export function useFormatMessage(messageId) {
  return useIntl().formatMessage({ id: messageId })
}
```

Comment: 2023 here from the future: can't use hooks in functions:

React Hook "useIntl" is called in function "useFormatMessage" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 17):

**For Input placeholder** for more [details](https://medium.com/@kamaldlk/how-to-use-react-intl-bb98c9a185b6)

```
   <FormattedMessage id="yourid" defaultMessage="search">
    {placeholder=>  
        <Input placeholder={placeholder}/>
        }
    </FormattedMessage>
```

Comment: IMO this is better than the injection way.

Comment: This is the best solution on the page and the only one to solve my problem, as `id="yourid"` was required

Comment: This method works for me as well. The simplest way over there to solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

As from React version >= 16.8, you can use [useIntl hook](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/API.md#useintl-hook) :

```
import React from 'react';
import { IntlProvider, useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const FunctionComponent = () => {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const lang = "en";
    const messages = {
      en: {
        'placeholderMessageId': 'placeholder in english',
      },
      fr: {
        'placeholderMessageId': 'placeholder en fançais',
      }
    }
    return ( 
      <IntlProvider locale = {lang} messages = { messages[lang] } >
          <input placeholder = { intl.formatMessage({ id: 'placeholderMessageId' })}/> 
      </IntlProvider >
      );
    };

export default FunctionComponent;
```

Comment: How about non-functional component ? I tried your solution but I get hook error

Comment: You may wanna check the first answer using injectIntl

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest this solution :

```
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const intl = useIntl();

  return (
    <input placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "messageId" })} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [react intl wiki](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) the implementation of an input box with translatable placeholder will look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { injectIntl, intlShape, defineMessages } from 'react-intl';

const messages = defineMessages({
  placeholder: {
    id: 'myPlaceholderText',
    defaultMessage: '{text} and static text',
  },
});

const ComponentWithInput = ({ intl, placeholderText }) => {
  return (
    <input
      placeholder={ intl.formatMessage(messages.placeholder, { text: placeholderText }) }
    />
  );
};

ComponentWithInput.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired
};

export default injectIntl(ComponentWithInput);
```

and the useage of it:

```
import ComponentWithInput from './component-with-input';
...
render() {
  <ComponentWithInput placeholderText="foo" />
}
...
```

The `id: 'myPlaceholderText',` part is necessary to enable the [babel-plugin-react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl) to collect the messages for translation.

Comment: Really nice example !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render a React component named FormattedMessage into a placeholder tag which is expecting a string.

You should instead just create a function named FormattedMessage that returns a string into the placeholder.

```
function FormattedMessage(props) {
    ...
}

<input placeholder=`{$(FormattedMessage({...messages.placeholderIntlText})}` />
```

Comment: Bryan is probably asking about react-intl, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186297/how-to-retrieve-a-string-in-reactintl-2-0-without-using-formattedmessage

Answer (score 1):

Consider this possibility.

**The simplest solution**

```
<IntlMessages id="category.name">
    {text => (
        <Input placeholder={text} />
    )}
</IntlMessages>
```

OR

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code in a picture. Use `codeboxes`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the whole app in one file, so using `export` wouldn't work. This one uses the normal class structure so you can use the state and other functionality of React if needed.

```
class nameInputOrig extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;
    return (
        <input type="text" placeholder={formatMessage({id:"placeholderIntlText"})} />
    );
  }
}

const nameInput = injectIntl(nameInputOrig);
```

Apply using the created constant:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        <nameInput />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the @gazdagerg 's answer, I have adapted his code in order to:

- having a new component that is a wrapper over an *input*
- receives an ID of a string from locale conf
- based on the ID, it returns the string in respect to the global locale setting
- handling the situation when the string ID is not set (this caused exception and page to crash)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { injectIntl, intlShape, defineMessages } from 'react-intl';


    const InputWithPlaceholder = ({ intl, placeholder }) => {

      const messages = defineMessages({
        placeholder: {
          id: placeholder,
          defaultMessage: '',
        },
      });

      if(messages.placeholder.id) {
        return (
          <input placeholder={ intl.formatMessage(messages.placeholder) } />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <input/>
        );
      }
    };

    InputWithPlaceholder.propTypes = {
      intl: intlShape.isRequired
    };

    export default injectIntl(InputWithPlaceholder);
```

You can use it in other file by:

1. import the new component
2. use it with the ID of the locale string as parameter

```
import InputWithIntlPlaceholder from 'your/path/to/component/InputWithIntlPlaceholder';

... more code here ...

<InputWithIntlPlaceholder placeholder="your.locale.string.id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-intl Imperative API](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api).

```js
import {useIntl} from "react-intl";

export default function Input() {
    const translate = (key) => useIntl().formatMessage({id: key})

    return <input placeholder={translate('your-translation-key')}/>
}
```

You can outsource `translate()` as you whish.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```jsx
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { injectIntl, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
 
/**
* {
* "hello": "Hello",
* "world": "World"
* }
*/
 
// pure function
const PureFunciton = injectIntl(({ intl }) => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'hello' })}</p>
    <p><FormattedMessage id="world" /></p>
  </div>
)
});
 
// class Component
class componentName extends Component {
  handleStr = () => {
    // return 'Hello';
    const { intl } = this.props;
    return intl.formatMessage({ id: 'hello' })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.handleStr()}</p>
        <p><FormattedMessage id="world" /></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default injectIntl(connect(componentName));
```