# How to use FormattedMessage in input placeholder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I know there is the similar question here:

[React-Intl How to use FormattedMessage in input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630620/react-intl-how-to-use-formattedmessage-in-input-placeholder)

But I am using TypeScript.

this code:

```
import { injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired
}
```

does not work for me.

How to set this place holder with formatted message.

```
<InputPass
  placeholder="Enter password"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the [`formatMessage`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) function from react-intl.

So you can do:

```
<InputPass
    placeholder={intl.formatMessage("messageKey")}
/>
```

If your issue is more with typing injectIntl with typescript. You can do the following:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  /* non injected props */
}
interface MyComponentInjectedProps extends MyComponent {
  intl: InjectedIntl;
}

class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentInjectedProps, {}> {
    ...
}

export default injectIntl<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent)
```

Note how we passed `ComponentProps` as a type argument so when you use the component from elsewhere typescript doesn't complain about the `intl` property not being passed.