# React Intl- Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-intl

```
  ....
 const func1 = (intl) => {
  const text = intl.formatMessage({id: 'mesage'});
  const func2 = () => {
     return {
      <div>.....
      placeholder={text}</div>
   };
  };
    return {
   <div>.....
   {func2()}</div>
  };
 };
```

export default withStyles(styles)(injectIntl(component));`}

I'm trying to to injectIntl to translate strings using react-intl library, but I keep getting following error:

"Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined"

I am trying to do something like this:
[React-Intl How to use FormattedMessage in input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630620/react-intl-how-to-use-formattedmessage-in-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Use This Way..!**

**The Simplest Solution For PlaceHolder Antd.**

```
    import {injectIntl} from "react-intl";

    class DemoForm extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const {getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
            const {intl} = this.props;
            const placeholder = intl.formatMessage({id:'enterHere'});
            return (
                <Form.Item label={<FormattedMessage id='name'/>}>
                    {getFieldDecorator('name',)(<Input placeholder={placeholder}/>)}
                </Form.Item>
            )
       }
}
export const Demo = injectIntl(Form.create()(DemoForm));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'mesage'});`, `intl` object is included in props.

Further assuming `Mycomponent` is wrapped then :

```
const MyComponent = ({intl}) => { // we are extracting intl from prop object
// component code here
}
```

Comment: Please accept or upvote if your question is answered thanks

Comment: it works but gives a warning error: "Must use destructing props assignment"

Comment: Then you can use `const {intl} =  props;`, depends if your component is class component then `const {intl} =  this.props;  and then use `intl.formatMessage({id: 'mesage'});`

Comment: okay that worked I think. I cant upvote you, since I'm low feedback. Thank you so much though

Comment: I have another function "MyComponent.defaultprops  that requires me to do the same, but its located outside the MyComponent. How can I translate string in this case?

Comment: You can also wrap that component in `injectIntl`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reimporting the `intl` in the class:

```
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";

const MyClass = (props) => {

    const intl = useIntl();
    return ( 
      ...
      {intl.formatMessage({ id: "message" })    // <==now it works}
      ...
    )
}
```